# Certain relations are added to the product entity for no reason

Tags: orocommerce

I have been using OroCommerce's API for creating products through POST requests. The request works fine but I have one problem once the entity has been created. For some reason, OroCommerce will add extra relations to the product entity.

For example, if I create a product with the name "testt", the request will have the following data :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "type": "products",
    "attributes": {
        ...
    },
    "relationships": {
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "productnames",
          "id": "name"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "productnames",
      "id": "name",
      "attributes": {
        "fallback": null,
        "string": "testt"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "localization": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

But when I send the POST request, the resulting entity I get has 2 name relationships instead of one, here's what the data of the resulting entity looks like with a GET request and including `names` :

```json
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "productnames",
      "id": "450",
      "attributes": {
        "string": null,
        "fallback": "system"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "product": {
          "data": {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "445"
          }
        },
        "localization": {
          "data": {
            "type": "localizations",
            "id": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "productnames",
      "id": "451",
      "attributes": {
        "string": "testt",
        "fallback": null
      },
      "relationships": {
        "product": {
          "data": {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "445"
          }
        },
        "localization": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
```

As you can see, the resulting object has an extra name relationship, even though it was never in the initial POST request to start with. I have the same issue with descriptions, shortDescriptions, where a relation with empty data gets created even if I explicitly set the data to `null` in the POST request.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The case is that every localizable field **MUST** have a value for every localization and one by default.

Such entities as

- productnames
- productdescriptions
- productshortdescriptions
- localizedfallbackvalues

can contain either a string value or fallback link to the default value or some other localization.

As is seen from your examples you have only one localization so when you create a product with

```
{
      "type": "productnames",
      "id": "name",
      "attributes": {
        "fallback": null,
        "string": "testt"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "localization": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    }
```

the system creates a "productnames" instance with a string value inside as a default value

```
{
      "type": "productnames",
      "id": "451",
      "attributes": {
        "string": "testt",
        "fallback": null
      },
      "relationships": {
        "product": {
          "data": {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "445"
          }
        },
        "localization": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    }
```

and then automatically adds "productnames" instances for each localization with fallback links (in your case one instance)

```
{
      "type": "productnames",
      "id": "450",
      "attributes": {
        "string": null,
        "fallback": "system"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "product": {
          "data": {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "445"
          }
        },
        "localization": {
          "data": {
            "type": "localizations",
            "id": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

An absence of localizable field default value in a POST body will trigger "Not Null constraint".

So as detailed above every localizable field **MUST** has a value (or fallback) for each localization. So every time a product or localization entity is created system adds a linking entity for every intersection of every localizable field and every localization.